# How to add multiple columns grouped by row in RDLC matrix?

Tags: rdlc

```
**Example Raw Data:**
Client ID      Client Plan ID
=========      ========
1              11
1              12
1              13
2              14
2              15

**Desired Result:**
Client ID      Client Plan ID 1      Client Plan ID 2      Client Plan ID 3
=========      ========              ========              ========
1              11                    12                    13
2              14                    15

**What I've tried(described below):**
Client ID      Client Plan ID       Client Plan ID       Client Plan ID       Client Plan ID      Client Plan ID
=========      ========             ========             ========             ========            ========
1              11                   12                   13
2                                                                             14                  15
```

I've tried row grouping by Client ID and column grouping by Client Plan ID and it creates a column for each unique Client Plan ID. I understand why it does this but I'm not sure how to tell it to re-use existing columns!

Any ideas?  I can change the raw data output if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Raw Data:**

```
Client ID      Client Plan ID     Index
=========      ========           =======
1              11                 1
1              12                 2
1              13                 3
2              14                 1
2              15                 2
```

Assign incremental indices to the Client Plans for each Client.  Then group by Index for your column group and by Client ID for your row group.